# The system is running in low-graphics mode, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers

I find similar questions on askubuntu but they are unable to solve my problem. My machine was working fine and today after an update it asked for restart. I did so. After reboot, it gave me an error message which has been reported many times and can be found at

[image]

After clcking <kbd>ok</kbd>, I got another error message of which I did not take a screenshot.

After some time the machine asked me to login and after login, when I tried to connect to wifi, it is not able to search any wifi. Since, it is showing searching option for a long time. I tried to update many times and restarted. Same is going on in each reboot. I tried to follow instructions given at following links (but none worked for me):

1. [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)
2. [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running low graphics mode | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686985/ubuntu-16-04-lts-running-low-graphics-mode)
3. [Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1968492)

Now, I don't know what else to do.

I am using Toshiba Satellite L650 laptop with dual boot.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: what was the second error message you didn't take a screenshot of? What exactly did you try from those posts and what happened? Does anything weird happen when you boot into the other OS, or only in Ubuntu? Please [edit] to add more information... oh and anything in `~/.xsession-errors`? About the wifi, consider running [the wireless info script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) to get more information about what's going wrong

Comment: @Zanna I didn't know at the time how can I take a screenshot, since, I didn't had other device to take picture of that. Sorry for that! I don't use other OS (windows) mostly so, I didn't try in that one. I shall write back after a trial. And I think there is no problem in other OS. 
`~/.xsession-errors` file include the text given bellow.[1]
For wireless, [https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos this script] doesn't work. Since, I used another trick which works for all above problems.[2]

Comment: I asked about other OS because you mentioned dual boot... have I misunderstood?

Comment: [1]
`openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0`

[2]
I removed all the files from directory `/var/crash/` and everything works fine in next boot.

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Comment: @Zanna No, I couldn't fix it yet, I got a temporary solution that I remove all files from `/var/crash/` then it works fine in next one boot. I have tried in other OS. Other OS is working fine. Since, I have taken screenshot of other message which was missing in my question: http://i.imgur.com/5xT9baY.png